# Linux как вернуться к процессу, запущеному в фоне

Tags: linux, консоль

Я подключаюсь по `SSH` к удаленному VDS. На VDS'e находиться файл `verificator.jar` — сервер для программы со встроенным контейнером. После запуска запускается... и ждет ввода. Возникла следующая ситуация:

---

Для того, чтобы иметь возможность выполнять другие действия и не убить процесс при выходе из сессии, которую создает `SSH`, я запускаю процесс следующим образом:

`java -jar verificator.jar параметр_1 параметр_2 &`

Однако, мне все же потребовалось вернуться к данной программе, после выпонения других команд. Возможно, пригодиться и продолжить ввод из под другой сессии.

---

Подскажите, как вернуться к процессу для дальнейшего взаимодействия, после запуска процесса оператором `&`?

Comment: для этого есть команда fg, Но лучше воспользоваться screen/tmux.

Comment: @KoVadim упомяни в ответе `jobs`. но лучше использовать `screen`, да

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для решения задачи лучше использовать screen/tmux. Они существуют для большинства линукс платформ.  screen работает как будто отдельный терминал. То есть, можно на сервере запустить десяток screen и переключаться между ними. При этом будет доступен весь вывод команды (который можно автоматом сохранять в файл).

Второе преимущество - устойчивость к отключениям. Если подключение к серверу случайно потеряется - ничего плохого не произойдет. Можно будет подключиться к серверу с другой машины, выполнить `screen -ls`, подсмотреть правильный сокет и потом к нему подключиться с помощью `screen -r сокет`. От работающего скрина всегда можно отключиться (отправив его в фон) нажатием <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>.

Если нужно запустить какую-то сложную задачу на удаленном сервере - screen/tmux обычно самое лучшее решение.

У скрина есть ещё одно преимущество. Если его скомпилировать правильно, то он поддерживает "мультисессию" - несколько человек может подключаться к одному терминалу.

Немного документации - https://www.opennet.ru/base/sys/screen2.txt.html

Работая на некоторых окружениях, можно заметить, как экран в скрине странно мерцает (что вызывает рвотные порывы). Это он просто так пытается "бипать". просто не может:). `vbell off` в конфиг решает эту проблему.

Comment: За "бипать" хотел поставить еще один плюс, но не вышло :)). Но все же: что это означает?

Comment: что такое "бипать"?

Comment: Последний абзац, вторая строка, вторая половина строки.

Comment: бипать - это от английского beep  - пищать. Если в терминале что то сделать "неправильно", к примеру, пытаться выйти за пределы строки или набирать очень быстро текст, то он пищит (раньше он пищал маленьким динамиком на материнке). screen это не всегда может и там оставили возможность "померцать экраном". Называется vbell - visual bell.

Comment: Так понятнее, спасибо!